# How to send email with IIS8.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

In my web application I have a ability to send email message, which works great when I debug it on my local machine, but since I deploy it to the server with IIS 8.5 it doesn't send email. Is there any special setting I need to do to enable smtp?

```
try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(emails);
            mail.From = new MailAddress("test@test.co.uk");
            mail.Subject = title;
            LinkedResource report = new LinkedResource(new MemoryStream(img), "image/png");
            var contentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            report.ContentId = contentId;
            var body = "<p style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, Century Gothic; font-size: 16px;'>" + content + "</p>";
            body = body + string.Format("<img src=\"cid:{0}\" />", contentId);
            var av1 = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, "text/html");
            av1.LinkedResources.Add(report);
            mail.AlternateViews.Add(av1);
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "mysmtphost.com";
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Port = 25;
            //smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            smtp.Send(mail);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Write("Execption in sendEmail:" + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
```

I have also set up SMTP service on the server and successfully send email using PowerShell, but again I cannot send email from the app even if I change to use PickupDirectoryFromIIS (the commented one).

Comment: What's defined within [`<mailSettings>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w355a94k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (or are you relying on explicit configuration options)? Also, have you debugged? Are there any messages/exceptions being returned?

Comment: Nothing in the mailSettings and as I said when I debug it on my local machine is working

Comment: Well, I would enable logging or setup trace messages and get as much insight into that box add possible. Something is obviously blocking it, and workout an error message it's difficult to diagnose.

Comment: How can I do it? When I run Chrome Developer Tool Networking, the POST request SendEmail, stay there in Pending status forever.

Comment: I had a similar problem when using Outlook.com as mailserver. It worked locally, but not when I published my site to the webserver. Outlook.com told me the webserver didn't have permission. I had to manually add it to some kind of list with authorized computers.

Comment: @Whistler: The call is done server-side;  a client-side debugger isn't going to offer anything. You need to either remote debug (through visual studio and attach to process), or add some form of trace logging ([System.Diagnostics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace).

Comment: The issue was not related to SMTP server, but IIS_User not having write permission to the drive. I was making a snapshoot of the webpage and sending it via email. Thanks everyone for help